# Какое железо нужно для программирования? В основном на Python

Tags: python, железо, процессор, ноутбук

Пишу на Python в pycharm. Немного на C++. Какого процессора будет достаточно для комфортного программирования? Сколько нужно ядер, частота и ОЗУ?

Comment: Абсолютно любое вообще. Я двендацать лет назад и на телефоне программировал

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Достаточно, чтобы браузер мог нормально держать, программировать Python можно в Google Colab например.

Comment: посмотрите РЕКОМЕНДОВАНЫЕ требования для pycharm и этого вполне хватит для всего

Comment: Рекомендованные требования оперативка не менее 4,но лучше 8 и все.

Comment: Продукты jetbrains и 4 гигабайта ОЗУ - это для любителей извращений. 8 - минимум для любителей. 12-16 уже хорошо. Но оно и на 64 и на 128 тупит:)

Comment: Я понимаю, что меньше 8 оперативы брать бессмысленно. Но что на счет ядер? 4 или 6. Понятно, что лучше 6, но много ли потеряю, если возьму 4 на 8 потоков с частотой 2,5!?

Comment: Лучше возьмите более быстрый ссд. Больше толку. Хотя я тут попробовал 20 ядерный и оно интересно на тяжёлых задачах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ориентируйтесь на [рекомендованные системные требования:](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html)

> 8 GB of total system RAM
>
> Multi-core CPU.
>
> SSD drive with at least 5 GB of free space
>
> Latest 64-bit version of Windows, macOS, or Linux (for example, Debian, Ubuntu, or RHEL)

Если думать о перспективе, то умножьте требования на два.

Требования к железу больше определяются задачами, которые вы будете решать. Нейронные сети потребуют быстрые CPU и GPU, много памяти, много места на диске. Веб разработка таких требований не предъявляет, но вам понадобится хороший монитор (возможно).

В любом случае нужен удобный монитор, клавиатура и мышь. Под тяжёлые вычислительные задача можно арендовать мощности в сети, но периферию вы таким образом не исправите.

Comment: Размыто. Multi-core. Два ядра тоже считается мульти. Знать бы точнее.

Comment: @АлександрШемякин чётких требований нигде никогда и не будет. Никто не мешает и на одном ядре программировать

Comment: а вопрос про обучение или какие задачи ? большенство учебных в 1 ядро делаются и от 20 там толку 0. там частоты побольше лучше чем ядер

Comment: В основном обучение. Но задачи не высоконагруженные. Но у меня в данный момент 2 ядра, частота 1.8 и там даже обычная компиляция кода выполняется не так быстро. Уже не говоря, что подвисают все остальные программы запущенные.

Comment: Что вы имеет в виду под "компиляция кода выполняется не так быстро"? В Питоне нет выделенной фазы компиляции. Интерпретатор компилирует модули в момент импорта, что может замедлить время первого запуска программы.